# Finding constant in probability density function

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

[image]

I'm new to this course, I googled similar problems and watched several videos on how to solve similar problems but I'm still not sure how to solve this problem.

As far as I understand the total area of $x^3-2x$ and $C\cdot tg2x$ is equal to $1$.

Am I supposed to find the area of $x^3-2x$ first and then subtract it from $1$?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, and then equate that to the integral of $C\cdot tg2x$ to find $C$

Comment: @RaadShaikh That's what I was thinking about too, I just don't understand how am I supposed to find the area of $x^3-2x$ if both parts of f(x) are unknown

Comment: You only need to find the area of $x^3-2x$ in the interval where $f(x)=x^3-2x$, namely, in $[-1,0]$. See the answer below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=1$. Given the piecewise definition of the function, we can split this as $$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}0\,dx+\int_{-1}^0 \left(x^3-2x\right)\,dx+\int_0^{\pi/8}\left(C\cdot tg2x\right)\,dx+\int_{\pi/8}^\infty 0\,dx=1\\
\implies\left.\frac{x^4}{4}-x^2\right|_{-1}^0~~+~~\left.\frac{-C}{2}\log|\cos2x|\right|_{0}^{\pi/8}=1\\
\implies \frac{3}{4}+C\frac{\log2}{4}=1\\
\implies C=\frac{1}{\log2}$$

I hope that clears up any confusion about the process!